# iOS 8.1 and Localized app

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I use Localizable.string for each language that the project supports.
I also localized the storyabord file so I have a file with the info as these:

```
/ * Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Subtitle"; ObjectID = "2Fy-d0-TVa"; * /
"2Fy-d0-TVa.text" = "Subtitle";
```

In my project I use NSLocalizedString to manage localization.

This has always worked well with

> iOS 7.0 7.1 8.0

On iOS 8.1 I can no longer have the localized application correctly! I visualize all the details in English. This simulator is on both of the device.

Apple has broken something?

Answer (score 0):

Localization in Xcode 6 has changed a little:

http://www.devfright.com/localization-xcode-6/